# If radio button is selected show alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, if-statement, radio-button

I want an alert to show when i click a radio button.

My radio buttons:

```
<div class="genericFormField">
   New:@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Form.InstallType, 1, Model.InstallationHeader.InstallType == 1 ? new { Checked = "checked" } : null )
   Pool:@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Form.InstallType, 2, Model.InstallationHeader.InstallType == 2 ? new { Checked = "checked" } : null)
   Refurb:@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Form.InstallType, 3, Model.InstallationHeader.InstallType == 3 ? new { Checked = "checked" } : null)              
</div>
```

So if the radio button new is selected i want an alert to say "NEW" otherwise nothing.

Normally it is easy because you have id but in this occasion there is no ID?

As this is RadioButtonFor.

Thanks

**New code**

Full code:

```
       $('input[name="Form.InstallType"]').on('change', function() {
            var val = $('input[name="Form.InstallType"]:checked').val();
            if (val === '1') {

                var validOptions = "@Url.Action("SerialProdNumStockSiteAutoComplete", "Ajax")?stocksitenum=LW&model=" + $("#Form_Prod_Num").val();
                previousValue = "";

                $('#abc').autocomplete({
                    autoFocus: true,
                    source: validOptions,

                }).change(function(){

                    var source = validOptions;
                    var found = $('.ui-autocomplete li').text().search(source);
                    console.debug('found:' + found);
                    var val = $('input[name="Form.InstallType"]:checked').val();

                    if (found < 0 && val === '1') {
                        $(this).val('');
                        alert("Please choose from auto complete");

                    }

                });


            }

        });
```

This works, however if the radio button is on page load it doesnt work, i have to click another radio button and then click "new" and then it will work..

any chance it works on if its checked already rather than when check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Html.RadioButtonFor creates a proper `input` with `name` and `id` attributes.

You can access the value this way:

```
$('input[name="Form.InstallType"]:checked').val();
```

Not sure about generated radios' name as it is an inner variable.
Render page and look at generated name. This is how it looks in my case.

Now, about your alert. You need to listen to `change` event.

```
$('input[name="Form.InstallType"]').on('change', function()
{
    var val = $('input[name="Form.InstallType"]:checked').val();        
    if (val === '1') alert('New');
});
```

Why '1'? Because you have set it in the ASP.NET code.
This is how it should look like.

```
<div class="genericFormField">
   New: @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Form.InstallType, 'new')
   Pool: @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Form.InstallType, 'pool')
   Refurb: @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Form.InstallType, 'refurb')              
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        AlertIfNewIsSelected(); // Check if it is selected on page load. According to the question in comments.
        $('input[name="Form.InstallType"]').on('change', AlertIfNewIsSelected);
    });

    function AlertIfNewIsSelected()
    {
        var val = $('input[name="Form.InstallType"]:checked').val();        
        if (val === 'new') alert('New');
    }
</script>
```

Of course, it all can be reached without using jQuery.

Comment: but how does that determine which radio button is selected, i want the new button selected.

Comment: @mali Oh, forgot about the main question. Edited.

Comment: quick question, what about on page load, can i also get an alert then, because new is normally selected one, the alert comes when i select another radio button and then re select new, but i want the alert whenever next is selected (on page load)?

Comment: @mali You cannot be sure that `new` will be always selected on page load. For instance, browsers have `autocomplete` functionality etc. You can check if it is checked after page load. I will edit my answer now.